# Send email from site through personalized email

Tags: sharepoint-designer, email

If I have a mailing list full of contacts, and in there is their email and a column to mark whether or not they get sent an email. How can I set up email bursts to come out of the Sharepoint site (using Sharepoint Designer or something) through a personalized email? So, when the clients receive our email, it comes from an email they recognize like my personal work email or something. Is that possible?

Comment: From designer using some kind of warkflow, you can not. Workflows will use the email address configured in the central administration.
Using the SPUtility.SendEmail you can personalize the sender address as you want

Comment: how does one use "SPUtility.SendEmail "

Comment: One will leave an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my point of view your best choice is create a custom Timer Job who will execute every day o once on a week... etc (totally configurable).

The code you could use will be like this:

```
var header = new StringDictionary();
header.Add("to", "to@mail.com");
header.Add("from", "custom_mail@mail.com");
header.Add("subject", "your subject");
header.Add("content-type", "text/html"); //will have html?
SPUtility.SendEmail(SPContext.Current.Web, header, emailBody);
```

In the next link you will find an awesome post to create a custom timer job: [Step by Step procedures to create a Timer Job in SharePoint 2013](http://www.sharepointpals.com/post/Step-by-Step-procedures-to-create-a-Timer-Job-in-SharePoint-2013)

Good luck